# How to create dependent factories using Factory Boy and SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, factory-boy

I'm currently struggling to get the foreign key of a tables index from another factory working.

My SQLAlchemy classes look as follows:

```
class Rfq(Base):
    __tablename__ = "rfq_rfq"

    id = Column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    title = Column(Text)
    description = Column(Text)
    creator_id = Column(
        ForeignKey(User.id, deferrable=True, initially="DEFERRED"), index=True
    )

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users_user"

    id = Column(
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
    )
    first_name = Column(String(150), nullable=False)
    last_name = Column(String(150), nullable=False)
    email = Column(String(254), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

With my factories as such:

```
class RfqFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Rfq
        sqlalchemy_session = Session
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = "commit"
   
    id = Sequence(lambda n: n)
    title = Faker("word")
    description = Faker("paragraph")
    creator_id = SubFactory(
        UserFactory,
    )

class UserFactory(SQLAlchemyModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        sqlalchemy_session = Session
        sqlalchemy_session_persistence = "commit"

    id = Sequence(lambda n: n)
    first_name = Faker("first_name")
    last_name = Faker("last_name")
    email = Faker("ascii_email")
```

When running my tests, this error is returned. It looks like the `creator_id` is being set to an SQLAlchemy object as opposed to the foreign key to the index of the Users table. I've tried playing around with `RelatedFactory`, however this doesn't seem to generate any data. I'm honestly stumped at this point, and would really appreciate any help.

```
self = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGDialect_psycopg2 object at 0x11230c880>
cursor = <cursor object at 0x1120705e0; closed: -1>
statement = 'INSERT INTO rfq_rfq (id, title, description, creator_id) VALUES (%(id)s, %(title)s, %(description)s, %(creator_id)s)'
parameters = {'creator_id': <tacto_api.repository.models.user.User object at 0x1123243a0>, 'description': 'Live purpose activity again perhaps. Certainly head since onto.', 'id': 0, 'title': 'population'}
context = <sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2.PGExecutionContext_psycopg2 object at 0x1123246d0>

    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) can't adapt type 'User'
E       [SQL: INSERT INTO rfq_rfq (id, title, description, creator_id) VALUES (%(id)s, %(title)s, %(description)s, %(creator_id)s)]
E       [parameters: {'id': 0, 'title': 'population', 'description': 'Live purpose activity again perhaps. Certainly head since onto.', 'creator_id': <tacto_api.repository.models.user.User object at 0x1123243a0>}]
E       (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)

../../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:717: ProgrammingError
```

Comment: Define `creator = relationship("User")` and then `creator = SubFactory(UserFactory)`.